# Passing json to server containing json array

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am trying to pass a json array inside JSON OBJECT . Issue is my array list contailns ids only which i have to loop through and pass to jsonarray  but my jsonarray is getting only value of last index of arraylist and replicating to the times of arraylist size .

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray category_ids_array = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject category_items = new JSONObject();


            jsonObject.put("category_ids", category_ids_array);


            for (int g=0 ;g < selectedCategories.size();g++)
            {
                category_ids_array.put(category_items);

                category_items.put("id",selectedCategories.get(g).getId());
                Log.d("catids",String.valueOf(selectedCategories.get(g).getId() ) );

            }
```

selectedCategories arraylist contains:
1937,1994,13365 ;

```
jsononject: {"category_ids":[{"id":13365},{"id":13365},{"id":13365}]}
```

Comment: please add your json

Comment: UPDATED MY ANSWER

Comment: please format your question

Comment: Sir what i need to format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i got it what i was doing wrong. I needed to create JSONObject newly each time.

```
for (int g=0 ;g < selectedCategories.size();g++)
        {
            JSONObject category_items = new JSONObject();

            category_items.put("id",selectedCategories.get(g).getId());
            Log.d("catids",String.valueOf(selectedCategories.get(g).getId() ) );

category_ids_array.put(category_items);

        }
```